# Clearing/Resetting all string and variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a routine in xcode that calls a function and spits out a result to a UITextView element on an iPhone app.

Before the routine is started I want to reset all NSString objects/values and any variables that I used to calculate the result. Is there a quick way to do this?

So far no matter what I retype in the UITextField it just gets ignored after the initial calculation.

Code for the solve button :-

```
- (IBAction)Solve:(id)sender {

    //
    // Reset strings and variable code here
    //

    [_Number1 resignFirstResponder];
    [_Number2 resignFirstResponder];
    [_Number3 resignFirstResponder];
    [_Number4 resignFirstResponder];
    [_Number5 resignFirstResponder];
    [_Number6 resignFirstResponder];
    [_TargetNum resignFirstResponder];
    // Dismiss Keyboard

    int numb1,numb2,numb3,numb4,numb5,numb6,numTar;

    numb1 = [self.Number1.text intValue];
    numb2 = [self.Number2.text intValue];
    numb3 = [self.Number3.text intValue];
    numb4 = [self.Number4.text intValue];
    numb5 = [self.Number5.text intValue];
    numb6 = [self.Number6.text intValue];
    numTar = [self.TargetNum.text intValue];

    mainLoopOne(numb1,numb2,numb3,numb4,numb5,numb6,numTar);
    // Start calculation with field values

    readAnswers = @"Please read answers bottom-up.\n";

    cantCalc = NULL;
    finalResult = @"";

    if (numb1 != 0) {

    int ii;

    for(ii = 0; ii < 6 ; ii++) {
       if (allAnswers[ii] != NULL) {
        finalResult = [finalResult stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", allAnswers[ii]];
       }
    }


    if (finalResult == NULL) {
        cantCalc = @"Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be possible, as there was no answer calculated.\n";
        readAnswers = @"";
    }

    CompileText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\nfrom %d combination tries.", readAnswers, finalResult, countCombi];

    [self.TextWin setText:CompileText];

    }

    countCombi = 0;

}

@end
```

Most of the strings and variables are set just under the #import "ViewController.h" so they are global :-

```
NSString *readAnswers;
NSString *cantCalc;
NSString *finalResult;
NSString *allAnswers[10];
NSString *CompileText;
NSString *readAnswers;
NSString *finalResult;

#define DIV 0
#define MUL 1
#define ADD 2
#define SUB 3


int n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6;
int answer_counter = 0;
int tar2 = 0;
int number[6];
int target = 0;
int used[6];
int countCombi;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the code ?

Comment: Please show your code and describe the exact problem (input, actual output, expected output ...)

Answer (score 0):

Create a reset method that alloc inits every string in your view controller again. You can set the textview's text to "".

In theory you could write a helper class that you pass in an object (your view controller) and it uses introspection to reset everything that is a string or whatever you want. This is a good approach for modularity and reusability, however it requires knowledge of c, and introspection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes whatever williams say thats correct. Implement like below:

```
    -(IBAction)doClear:sender
         {
  [Yourtextview setString];
          }
```